# Unable to install Shutter in Lubuntu 18.10

Tags: lubuntu, shutter

So I got this PPA to install this application mentioned here : http://shutter-project.org/faq-help/ppa-installation-guide/

But when I add it and attempt to update, it throws a 404.

Is there any way I can install this awesome screenshot tool in Lubuntu 18.10?

Note - I noticed that on the official page there is a *tar* file but I really want to keep the app updated. Besides when I download it it throws errors about unmet dependencies regarding Gnome.

Comment: The PPA go up to 16.04 version only. It is unlikely to be updated ever again. You need to find other ways to install or find another software.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thats a shame. And really weird, the last version of the software is from September this year. :(

Comment: It's available as snap and those are curated by the snap store and should receive updates.

Comment: It can and *should* be installed with Ubuntu Software tool ;) . 10 years old guides are almost always useless.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Snap is the right answer. Consider posting it as an answer so we can vote for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Official Ubuntu repositories

For older Ubuntu versions such as 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS - Shutter is located in [*universe* repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=shutter):

> [image: Shutter in APT]

## Snap

Please note that Snap version is not yet released for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS and 18.10:

```
$ snap find shutter
No matching snaps for "shutter"
```

Also you can check [search on snapcraft.io site](https://snapcraft.io/search?category=&q=shutter):

> [image: Shutter is not found on snapcraft.io site]

## Third-party PPA

You can consider to [find third-party PPA for Shutter](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=shutter). I found one - [`ppa:linuxuprising/shutter`](https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/shutter?field.series_filter=cosmic).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/shutter
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

then enjoy the application:

[image: Shutter on Ubuntu MATE 18.10]

---

**Note:** I have e-mailed to Shutter team about official package for Cosmic.

Comment: Thanks so much. I actually just mailed them too. :)

Comment: Hi guys, I received your mail and the answer is: There is no Shutter team, basically there is just me (I applied some patches which have been submitted on Launchpad in the past, also I maintain the Arch Linux package for Shutter) and Vadim (who has access to the official website and publishes update announcements). The actual Shutter developer, Mario, resigned a few years ago and therefore Shutter is basically abandon-ware. Unfortunately none of us is experienced with Ubuntu packaging and therefore we cannot provide a PPA (or keep the official PPA up to date). However, help is welcome!

Comment: So if there is somebody who has some experience in Ubuntu packaging and PPAs, we will gladly give him access to the official PPA so he can keep it up to date.